# AS3: removing a lineStyle in the middle of drawing a shape

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing, shapes

I want to draw a large red circle with a black outline and a smaller concurrent green circle with no outline. But when I draw the small green circle, it has the same lineStyle as the big red circle. There does not seem to be any kind of endLineStyle method. Setting the lineStyle thickness to 0 does not work either. I realize there are a number of other things I could do like draw them as separate shapes, or make the small green circle's lineStyle also green, but I was wondering if there was some way get rid of the lineStyle without doing that.

```
var s:Shape = new Shape();
s.graphics.lineStyle(4,0x000000);
s.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
s.graphics.drawCircle(100,100,80);
s.graphics.endFill();
s.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
s.graphics.drawCircle(100,100,40);
s.graphics.endFill();
addChild(s);
```

Comment: One work around that would at least allow you to make them as one shape would be to draw black filled circle and then a red, smaller circle on that and then your green circle. No lines at all. I know that doesn't answer your question, but in case you just really wanted them to be the same shape, that could sort of do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
s.graphics.lineStyle();
```

The first argument is `thickness`, `null` by default.
 
 
A call with zero `thickness` - `s.graphics.lineStyle(0);` or `alpha` - `s.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 0);` has the same effect

Comment: Setting thickness to 0 doesn't work. The inner green circle still has a black outline, albeit a thin one.